# Swift 3 - Cannot override 'imagePickerController'

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, swift3, xcode8

My code:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    self.image = image
    self.imageStatusLabel.text = "There is a picture"
    self.imageStatusLabel.textColor = UIColor.blue()

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And this is the error:

> Cannot override 'imagePickerController' which has been marked unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

Well, I've tried to use the newer function:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // But no image in the parameters
}
```

But then, there is no image in the parameters and I can get the image.

What should I do?

Answer (score 11):

You have to use the info parameter and make a cast to `UIImage`. Don't forget that you have to put a "`Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`" and a "`Privacy - Camera Usage Description`" in the `info.plist` file and fill the values with a string explaining the reason for request the access to photo library and camera.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        pictureImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        pictureImageView.image = pickedImage
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To use `imagePickerController` in `Swift3` you need add a row with key: `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` and value is a `string` (e.g: "*Access to your photos*") to **Info.plist** file and  let's try below:

```
class YourController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    let imagePickerButton: UIButton = {
        let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
        btn.setTitle("Choose a Photo", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = .blue
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePickerDidTap), for: .touchUpInside)

        return btn
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(imagePickerButton)
    }

    func handlePickerDidTap() {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        print("photo is selected")
        // do some thing here
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 1):

You get the image from the passed `info` dictionary, see the keys in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys)

You probably want either

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
```

or

```
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func selectPhotoLibrary(_ sender: Any) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
        picker.sourceType = .camera
    } else{
        print("Kamera desteklenmiyor.")
    }
    present(picker, animated: true, completion:nil)
}

@IBAction func selectPhotoCamera(_ sender: Any) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(picker, animated: true, completion:nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
    guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) else { return }
    self.imageView.image = image
    print(imageData)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

Read more for usage detail --> [https://medium.com/@yakupad/swift-uiimagepickercontroller-kullanımı-91771ed4c1d6](https://medium.com/@yakupad/swift-uiimagepickercontroller-kullan%C4%B1m%C4%B1-91771ed4c1d6)